# How to create image CvSeq

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I want to create an image with CvSeq .

i have this code:

```
CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(
            img,
            cascade,
            storage,
            1.1,
            3,
            0 /*CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNNING*/,
            cvSize( 40, 40 ) );
```

and want to create an new image with CvSeq faces.

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish? faces contains a list of rectangles where faces were found. How do you want to create a new image with them?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example from OpenCV wiki pages.
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

Comment: thanks man, but i dont want to know how to detect face, but want to create new image with cvseq metod.

Comment: cvseq is a data structure used to store multiple faces(i.e. their coordinates), I dont understand, how do you wish to create images from it.